# How can I get a count of the total number of digits in a number in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Declaration of a number variable called `temp` in TypeScript:

```
temp: number = 0.123;
```

How can I get a count of the total number of digits in a number (which is 3)?

Comment: Why 3 rather than 4?

Comment: How is the number of digit 3 in your example?

Comment: do a split (or substring) on '.' put the last part after the split in a variable and perform a count?

Comment: `String(0.123).match(/\d/g).length`

Comment: `String(temp).replace(/^0\.0*|0+$|\./, "").length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in typescript simply use:

> this.number.toString().split('.'))[1].length

Where this.number is Type of Number

Answer (score 5):

If I understood correct, you want the part after `.`.

You can parse it into a string, `split` by  `.` and count the string length of the second item.

```js
const temp = 0.123;
const tempArray = temp.toString().split('.');

const length = tempArray[1].length;

console.log(length);
```

Comment: @messerbill Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regexp `\.\d+`

```js
var temp = 0.123;
var regex = new RegExp('\\.\\d+', 'g');
console.log(temp.toString().match(regex).pop().length - 1);
```